# If syntax not correct in batch script

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error

My code is :

```
@echo off
set /a var = %date:~-10,2%
IF ("%var%" EQU "3") 
(
echo hello
)
ELSE 
(
echo no
)
```

it is giving syntax error.

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `IF /?`. The syntax is pretty clear in the help file.

Comment: The syntax is according to that only, still it is giving error..

Comment: done.. still getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /a var = %date:~-10,2%
IF ("%var%" EQU "3")
```

This code is setting `var` to the value of the first 2 of the last 10 characters of the date.

It will fail if these 2 characters are `08` or `09` as a leading `0` in batch indicates an *octal* value. Unless you are using suppressed-leading-zero for that item, you need

```
set /a var = 1%date:~-10,2% - 100
```

that is, string those 2 characters after `1` (making 101..131, assuming you are selecting the day digits) then subtract `100`.

The `if` statement is attempting to compare the literal string '("*the value of var*"'  to '"3")' These two strings will never be equal. The syntax error is because the `(` **must** be on the same physical line as the `if`, ie you need

```
IF %var% EQU 3 (
```

If you use the quotes like this

```
IF "%var%" EQU "3" (
```

It *will* work because you set `var` using a `set /a`. If you had simply used the substring `%date:~-10,2%` then since that has a length 2, this *literal* comparison would need to be `03` or `3` depending entirely on your date-format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the position of the brackets.

Try this:

```
@echo off
set /a var = %date:~-10,2%
IF "%var%" EQU "3" (
echo hello
) ELSE (
echo no
)
```